# How to set the Hardware Encoder using Android APIs for WebRTC

Tags: android, webrtc, webrtc-android

I am using version 1.0.28513 and am not sure how/where to specify VP8 as my video codec for hardware acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

Giving a look to this [wonderful example](https://vivekc.xyz/getting-started-with-webrtc-part-4-de72b58ab31e) in Kotlin:

```
private val peerConnectionFactory: PeerConnectionFactory by lazy {
    //Initialize PeerConnectionFactory globals.
    val initializationOptions = PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions.builder(this)
            .setEnableVideoHwAcceleration(true)
            .createInitializationOptions()
    PeerConnectionFactory.initialize(initializationOptions)

    //Create a new PeerConnectionFactory instance - using Hardware encoder and decoder.
    val options = PeerConnectionFactory.Options()
    val defaultVideoEncoderFactory = DefaultVideoEncoderFactory(
            rootEglBase.eglBaseContext, /* enableIntelVp8Encoder */true, /* enableH264HighProfile */true)
    val defaultVideoDecoderFactory = DefaultVideoDecoderFactory(rootEglBase.eglBaseContext)
    PeerConnectionFactory(options, defaultVideoEncoderFactory, defaultVideoDecoderFactory)
}
```

and to the corresponding [Java class](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/master/sdk/android/api/org/webrtc/DefaultVideoEncoderFactory.java):

```
/** Create encoder factory using default hardware encoder factory. */
public DefaultVideoEncoderFactory(
    EglBase.Context eglContext, boolean enableIntelVp8Encoder, boolean enableH264HighProfile) {
  this.hardwareVideoEncoderFactory =
        new HardwareVideoEncoderFactory(eglContext, enableIntelVp8Encoder, enableH264HighProfile);
}

/** Create encoder factory using explicit hardware encoder factory. */
DefaultVideoEncoderFactory(VideoEncoderFactory hardwareVideoEncoderFactory) {
    this.hardwareVideoEncoderFactory = hardwareVideoEncoderFactory;
}
```

should help you figure out where to act